# Microsoft MSAL - aquire token to multiple scopes

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

In Azure Active Directory, I have an app that need to use both MicrosoftGraphAPI and SharePointAPI with the following scopes:

`GraphAPI scopes:`

```
"https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All",
"https://graph.microsoft.com/Group.Read.All",
"https://graph.microsoft.com/Sites.Read.All",
"https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read.Shared",
"https://graph.microsoft.com/MailboxSettings.Read",
"https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read.All"
```

`SharePointAPI scopes:`

```
"https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/AllSites.Read",
"https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/AllSites.FullControl",
"https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/User.Read.All"
```

I'm trying to get token for for the app:

```
from msal import PublicClientApplication
AUTHORITY = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common'

scopes = [ "https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/AllSites.Read",
           "https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/AllSites.FullControl",
           "https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/User.Read.All"
           "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All",
           "https://graph.microsoft.com/Group.Read.All",
           "https://graph.microsoft.com/Sites.Read.All",
           "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read.Shared",
           "https://graph.microsoft.com/MailboxSettings.Read",
           "https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read.All"
         ]

app = PublicClientApplication(client_id, authority=AUTHORITY)
flow = app.initiate_device_flow(scopes=scopes)
```

But after approving the app in the WebUI, I get the following error:

```
'error_description': 'AADSTS28000: Provided value for the input parameter scope is not valid 
because it contains more than one resource. Scope https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read.Shared 
https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read.All https://graph.microsoft.com/Group.Read.All 

https://graph.microsoft.com/MailboxSettings.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Sites.Read.All 

https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/AllSites.FullControl 
https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/AllSites.Read https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/User.Read.All 
offline_access openid profile is not valid'
```

Answer (score 7):

That's the expected behavior. You cannot mix resources (graph, sharepoint, etc) but you can [acquire 1 access token for each additional resource using the same refresh token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens).

You can achieve this in MSAL [calling the following method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication.microsoft-identity-client-ibyrefreshtoken-acquiretokenbyrefreshtoken?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Identity_Client_PublicClientApplication_Microsoft_Identity_Client_IByRefreshToken_AcquireTokenByRefreshToken_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__System_String_):

```cs
PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenByRefreshToken(IEnumerable<string> scopes, string refreshToken);
```

Comment: I didn't know this was expected behavior. Thanks for clearing that up :)

Comment: Could anyone points me to the MS document that says we can't mix resources type?

Comment: The link above is outdated. Although the answer is the same, the latest doc is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-user-gets-consent-for-multiple-resources

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good resource for fixing your issue: https://camerondwyer.com/2022/03/11/how-to-combine-graph-sharepoint-permission-consent-into-a-single-msal-dialog-on-first-use/

If you happen to use a MSAL.js wrapper like the one available for Angular, this works out of the box via its interceptor. You only need to supply all the scopes in the login request and once user gives consent, the access tokens for specific resources are silently fetched on demand.