# Blazor WASM with Azure AD – How do I get multiple user permission / scope consents

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

I have a Blazor web assembly application (the client), ASP.NET core hosted (the server).

I have setup Azure AD as per this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-7.0

I also require some additional scopes / permissions in Azure AD as the server need to make calls to both power BI and Microsoft Graph on behalf of the user (delegated permissions), so I have added these to the server app registration in AAD.

[image]

In my development environment I have granted admin consent to these permissions, so the end user does not need to consent. This is working.

In the live environment I am unable to grant admin consent to the permissions, meaning I will need the end user to consent.

**Can anyone tell me how to do this, or direct me to the documentation?**

[image]

I have tried adding the additional scopes to the client app, whilst this does present the additional consent to the user at login, the token request fails as multiple scope types cannot be requested for one token. So it looks as though the MSAL library performs the auth part, but then tries to request all scopes in the token request.

*There was an error trying to log you in: '28000 AADSTS28000: Provided value for the input parameter scope is not valid because it contains more than one resource. Scope api://XXXX/API.Access https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All openid profile offline_access is not valid.*

Even if this did work, those scopes would be consented in the client app registration and not the server, so I’m not sure that this would be the correct approach anyway.

Comment: about the error message, that's because you added `more than one resource`, we can't not put our own custom API(api://xxx/scopename) and other kind of api(graph api, powerbi) together. one time one kind.

Comment: in the meantime, I didn't find a way to use on-behalf-flow to give user consent, because user consent should have a UI to let user click. So I'm afraid we can only give the user consent in client but not the hosted server. because I had a test by auth code flow before, once user give user consent for an API permission which doesn't have admin consent when generating auth code, even we use this auth code to acquire an access token doesn't contain this API permission, the API permission would also contained in the access token.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got the results like below:***

I created an **`ServerApp`**, exposed an API and granted below API permissions:

[image]

I created an **`ClientApp`** and granted API permissions like below:

[image]

Now, for ***sample*** I tried to **authorize the users** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope= api://ServerAppClientID/API.Access https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All openid profile offline_access
&state=12345
```

The **code** got generated successfully like below:

[image]

Now, I generated the **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:api://ServerAppID/API.Access https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All openid profile offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

Using the same scope as you, **I got the same error** like below:

[image]

> **Note** that: In OAuth 2.0 process, only one resource can be accessed by a single authentication request.

I agree with *@Tiny Wang*, To resolve the error you need to access one resource at a time, we cannot include the two different APIs together.

- User consent can be given only to the **`ClientApp`** not the **`ServerApp`**.

**Hence**, pass one resource in the scope like below:

```json
scope:api://ServerAppID/API.Access
```

[image]

**As a workaround**, using the same refresh token you can acquire one access token for each resource like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:refresh_token
client_secret:ClientSecret
refresh_token:RefreshToken
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All
```

[image]

```cs
PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenByRefreshToken(IEnumerable<string> scopes, string refreshToken);
```

**Reference:**

[sharepoint - Microsoft MSAL - aquire token to multiple scopes - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429249/microsoft-msal-aquire-token-to-multiple-scopes) by AlfredoRevilla-MSFT & Elnino